# Force angular scope to update from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've create an angular controller and service. In my service I have an array that starts off blank when the app loads, but is filled later on. In my controller I have a property on $scope that points to that array. When the array in the service is updated I assumed the $scope property would also be updated and the DOM would update accordingly. Here is the sample code.

```
app.controller("myCtlr", ["$scope", "$service", function($scope, $service){

   $scope.friends = $service.friends

}]);

app.factory("$service", function($http){

   var friends = {};

   friends = {

      get: function(){
        $http.get("/someurl").success(function(data){

           // data is the array of friends
           friends = data; 

        });           
      }

   };



});
```

I've tried using `angular.extend` but there aren't many good example of it online so I don't fully understand it yet. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular `$http` automatically kicks off a digest cycle, you should also `return friends` from your service and also use `.then` to continue the promise pattern:

```
app.factory("$service", function($http){

    var friends = {};

    friends = {

    get: function(){
        $http.get("/someurl").then(function(data){
            return data.data
        });    
    }

    return friends;
});
```

And in your controller:

```
$service.friends.get().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: this first `var friends = {};` is superfluous. You should assign the next object literal directly.